# How to view Chg% in separate pane on the Trading View web application?

Tags: trading

Basically I want to visualize multiple ticker's Chg% which is on the right side of the charts in a separately new pane. If someone can explain in steps, I'll be really grateful.

TradingView application:

[image: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/mnI2nwFf/?symbol=NSE%3AMSUMI]

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "visualize multiple ticker's Chg% on the right side of the charts in a separately new pane". Perhaps you could illustrate by using a drawing.

Comment: @Flux : Maybe my question may sound a bit confusing(sorry for that). I want to show all the ticker's Chg% using a line chart in a separate pane(Like a multiple line chart).